# Link tables are not updating when form is submitted in ms access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Link tables are not updating which are connected to two tables or more tables

For instance : - There is a Evaluator table containing id and Evaluator name and other table - form which is having other columns with primary key and these two tables are joined by a link table which has both tables primary key. 
When user is filling the form in ms access, details related to other tables are storing in the main table but linked tables are not updating which causing an issue in a generating a report as those linked tables are empty.

Comment: Normally a form should do add/edit to 1 table. Are you using form/subform arrangement?

Comment: I am using only one form.

Comment: Hallo and Welcom, Cascading updates needs to be defined in Relationships

Comment: Well, therein likely lies the problem. Possibly should use form/subform. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b

Comment: Cascading updates are also not working..

Comment: But I believe subform concept is right.. I will check with it...

Comment: Cascade Update has nothing to do with entering new data. It is relevant when changing a primary key value for a particular record. The change will 'cascade' to dependent records. A db can function without establishing relationships.